# Disable Entity Framework logging in Azure Function

Tags: entity-framework, logging, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function in .net5 (a.k.a. `dotnet-isolated`) and I've added Entity Framework like this

```
services.AddDbContext<EfDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(context.Configuration[...], builder =>
    {
        builder.EnableRetryOnFailure();
    });
});
```

When I run the function I see the DB queries from EF in the console (info level judging by the color).

[image]

How can I disable them? I tried obvious options in my `host.json`:

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
    }
}
```

and

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
        "default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query": "Warning"
    }
}
```

or even

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
    }
}
```

but it didn't help. The only option which worked was

```
"logging": {
    "logLevel": {
        "default": "Warning",
    }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Could it be that you have custom logging? I would try to search for 'Executed DbCommand' in the project

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found a way. That's a bit strange though and I still wanna understand how it works and why it's done this way. Anyways, from AppInsights logs I found out that EF logs are written under the `Function.<YOUR_FUNCTION_NAME>.User` [category](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/configure-monitoring?tabs=v2#configure-categories). (turns out that a standard EF category is somehow overwritten by the functions runtime or so?).

That means that I can impact on the overall log level of a specific function by

```
    "logging": {
        "logLevel": {
            "Function.MyFunc1.User": "Debug",
            "Function.MyFunc2.User": "Warning"
        }
    }
```

in the `host.json`. It can be helpful but it doesn't solve my problem.

If however I now add a filter in the `Program.cs` like this:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
  .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
  ...               
  .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
  {
    builder.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.Warning);
  })
  ...
```

the EF info logs are gone.

Comment: just to possibly save someone`s time you need to reference using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging , my intellisense in VS2022 was not giving me this suggestion only displaying that AddFilter does not exist

Comment: Have you tried,:
builder.Logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.Warning);

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
builder.AddFilter("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", LogLevel.None);
```